# Can I dynamically resize firecracker microVMs during runtime to adjust vCPU capacity?

Tags: virtual-machine, serverless, esxi, hypervisor, firecracker

I wanted to implement a serverless platform where I can resize microvms based on load. For my idea to work, I need to resize microvm (firecracker VMM) with 2vcpu to 8vcpu and so on. Is this possible? If so, are there any tutorials to do this?

Thanks for the help!

I tried searching on google for any such documentation. I talked to some people and found that VMware's ESXI hypervisor allows such runtime resizing so I was wondering if we can do this in firecracker.